# Setting up dynamic commandText for log4net

Tags: c#, sql, log4net

Hey I am using Log4Net in my project. The code below is just from a testing project which I made for testing purpose only. I have multiple values for the commandText tag, so I want to make it dynamically. So far I tried to use a CustomColumn but this is just not working. I think because its not inserting SQL code.

```
    <log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="xx" Catalog="xx"; Integrated Security=True;"/>
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception], [AuftragsID]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @CustomColumn )" />
    ...other parameters
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@CustomColumn"/>
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{CustomColumn}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

This is my code

```
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(@"D:\Daten\x-NeissF\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AUSGABE\AUSGABE\Logging.config"));
        log.Info("Info logging");
        log.Debug("Debug");
        log.Error("ERROR");
        log.Fatal("FATAL");
        log.Warn("Warn");
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["CustomColumn"] = "SELECT ID_DBO_AUFTRAG FROM dbo.Auftrag WHERE CADSystem='Promis'";

    }
```

I need a function that is inserting a different commandText value. Something like in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112762/setting-up-dynamic-connection-string-for-log4net). But with a string which contains.

```
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception], [AuftragsID]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, SELECT ID_DBO_AUFTRAG FROM dbo.Auftrag WHERE CADSystem='Promis'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3hours I found a solution that works in my case.

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Data\.logging.config", Encoding.Default);
text = text.Replace("OriginalString", "NewString");
File.WriteAllText((@"D:\Data\logging.config"), text,Encoding.Default);
```

In that case I am changing the value in the insert into sql statement.

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception], [AuftragsID]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, SELECT data FROM dbo.table WHERE value='OriginalString' )" />
```